# If $H \subseteq G$ are finite abelian groups, how does $L^2(H)$ embed into $L^2(G)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, p-adic-number-theory, profinite-groups

If $H \subseteq G$ are abelian groups, how does $L^2(H)$ embed into $L^2(G)$?  In particular, I am trying to find the [Pontriyagin dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) of the p-adic numbers.

---

#### Example

Here is a rather stunning visualization of the $2$-adic case.  However, I could not translate this into Fourier series.

[image]

I am trying to understand how fourier series works on the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  These numbers are a direct limit:
$$ \mathbb{Z}_p = \lim_{\to} \mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$$
An element of this ring is a sequence of numbers $a_m$ such that if $m \leq n$ then $a_m \equiv a_n \mod p^m$, looking at the smaller exponent.

For any finite $k$ there is a meaninigful [discrete fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) and therefore it could be possible to extend this to the p-adic numbers.
We can define a sequence of functions:
$$ f_m: \mathbb{Z}/p^m \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C} $$
and it will have an expansion as a linear combination of waves $e_m(x) = e^{2\pi i  \,\frac{x}{p^m}}$.  This does not seem right.

Comment: I think my mistake is to [try](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583609/p-adic-numbers-and-group-characters) to embed $\mathbb{Z}_p$ inside the unit circle $S^1$ certainly not with the [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.  My goal is to write down explicit characters so I can evaluate a Fourier series in $p$-adic numbers (in fact in the [adeles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring), $\mathbb{A}$).

Comment: Your question does not really have much of an answer... If H is $\mathbb Z$ and G is $\mathbb R$ there is no sensible embedding.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez well... there are several.  You can place $a \mathbb{Z} + b \subset \mathbb{R}$ for any real numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ usually $b = 0$.  Is this the **canonical** choice? No, but we can always do something.

Comment: I don't understand in what way that is an embedding of $L^2$s.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Hmm... $L^2(\mathbb{Z}) \not \subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R})$ I think I left out the word "finite" in my question.  However, consider the [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) used to store real-time signals using discrete-time Fourier analysis.